# Python 2.7 and Sublime Text 2 Setup Guide

Tags: python-2.7, ide, sublimetext2

I am new to Sublime Text 2. Basically I want to setup Sublime T2 as a Python IDE.

I have come across various questions with regards to Python and Sublime T2, but I couldn't find a guide from a beginners perspective. This is what I have done so far:

1. Installed Python.
2. Installed Sublime T2.
3. Installed Sublime Package Control

What steps (e.g. package installations, etc.) should I follow to complete the Sublime Python IDE Setup?

Comment: My answer located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730866/set-up-python-3-build-system-with-sublime-text-3/46132747#46132747) also works for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 8):

Besides Package Control, I use the following packages for Python development:

- [SideBarEnhancements](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements)
- [All Autocomplete](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete)
- [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel)
- [GitGutter](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter)
- [Pylinter](https://github.com/biermeester/Pylinter)

I found *SublimeCodeIntel* and *Pylinter* to be especially helpful for writing Python code in Sublime Text.

Besides installing these packages you should also tweak some of Sublime's preferences. For example, Python can be quite picky about whitespace. Therefore I recommend taking extra care for setting up how Sublime handles whitespace. I'm using these settings (put them in *Preferences -> Settings - User*):

```
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
```

If you want to know more, I've written a blog post about setting up Sublime Text for Python development: https://dbader.org/blog/setting-up-sublime-text-for-python-development

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to select a build system in the `tools` menu.

[image: screenshot]

Then, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> will build, and pull up the interpreter for you.

EDIT: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> will also open your console, without building the project. From there, you can run Python commands with the built-in interpreter.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have done this part as well. What I need now is what other sublime packages do I need to install. And how to set sublime to use the python I installed instead of the python it comes with.

Answer (score 0):

I've documented my Sublime Text workflow [here](http://kirang.in/2013/05/04/my-sublime-workflow/). Hope this helps.