# Python with NLTK and GenSim

Tags: python, sublimetext2, nltk, gensim

Hello GenSim community. 
I am working with Python 2.7.5, and Sublime Text 2. I need to install Gensim. I have tried Enthought but it does not support NLTK. I need to import GenSim in Sublime Text 2. I tried all the command line instructions, to no success. Can someone please tell me how to get GenSim in ST2? I already have Scipy and Numpy installed. I have tried following instructions on the Radim Rehurek webpage, easy_install, and pip install etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "import GenSim in Sublime Text 2"? Are you trying to write a program that uses GenSim, and build it in Sublime? Are you using something like [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL)? Or are you trying to use Sublime's internal Python prompt and import modules there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 and Sublime Text 2 Setup Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257339/python-2-7-and-sublime-text-2-setup-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text is a text editor that can serve as an IDE (integrated dev environment), see http://www.sublimetext.com/

`NLTK` and `gensim` are python packages/libraries/modules. Here's a list of other libraries. https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsefulModules and `pip` is a nifty tool to handle the python packages installation/maintenance.

To install gensim, first install `pip`:

Debian:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Fedora:

```
$ sudo yum install python-pip
```

Others:

```
$ wget https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py
```

Then install `gensim` using `pip`:

```
$ pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Lastly, configure python in Sublime Text, see [Python 2.7 and Sublime Text 2 Setup Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15257339/python-2-7-and-sublime-text-2-setup-guide)
and http://dbader.org/blog/setting-up-sublime-text-for-python-development