# Configure Sublime Text to use Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I added the following build script:

```
{
"cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python3", "$file"]
, "selector": "source.python"
, "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

when I run `which python3`in terminal, i get the following: `/usr/local/bin/python3` which tells me that I have the correct path in the Sublime file.

However, when i run

```
import sys 
print(sys.version)
```

i still get

```
2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

I saved this new build system file under

> Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/User/Python3.sublime-build

Comment: I have looked through the related questions and even following those suggestions to the T is not working for me for whatever reason.

Comment: did you select your new build system from the Tools menu -> Build System?

Comment: @KeithHall Wow, well that is surely embarrassing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set up Python 3 build system with Sublime Text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730866/set-up-python-3-build-system-with-sublime-text-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @KeithHall pointed out, I haven't actually selected the new build system.