# Change the default path to open Python3 in Sublime Text (OS X)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I use `sublime text 3` to code my python script in OSX. However, whenever I create a new python script using `sublime text 3`, it automatically created the file in `Python2.7`. But I want to use `Python 3.6`. This is really annoying and sabotaging my working progress...

Is there any way to change the default path for Python in `sublime text 3`? Appreciated!!

Comment: refer this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730866/set-up-python-3-build-system-with-sublime-text-3

Comment: but it uses windows os. I use osx..

Answer (score 0):

on mac os terminal type:

```
$ which python3
```

Add the path to cmd key of json in .sublime-build file

Comment: where to find the json in .sublime-build file?

Comment: In sublime text go to Tools > Build System 
if you see python there, click on Build and see the output in the console below.
This will give you the overview of whether sublime text 3 is picking up the python3 installation of your device.
if you get something like python2.7 or so click on new build system and create a new build using the json as described earlier.
next time you run your program, use this build system and all should work fine.
But sublime text 3 should support python3 out of the box.Just check if python3 path is added to system path before doing the above

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on what was previously said.
After you find the path of Python3 with the `which` command;

- go to ***Tools--> Build System --> New Build System*** and paste the below into the file.
- Replace *PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON3* with your python3 path and save as "Python3.sublime-build". Now, Python3 should be an option to build with.

```py
{
  "cmd": ["PATH_TO_YOUR_PYTHON3", "-u", "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.python"
}
```