# No Build System : Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3, build-system

I can't seem to get the sublime build system to work, I get "**No build System**" when I try to run my code.

I've set build system to Automatic  under Tools->Build Systems, and the file has been save as Node.sublime-build in my Sublime Text settings folder.

These are the different variations I have tried below :

---

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe", "$file"] 
    "selector" : "*.js"
}
```

---

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe", "$file"] 
    "selector" : "source.js"
}
```

---

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe", "$file"] 
    "selector" : "*.js"
}
```

---

```
{
    "shell_cmd": ["C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe", "$file"] 
    "selector" : "*.js"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The `.sublime-build` file needs to be valid [JSON](http://json.org/)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741296/5267751).

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace). Each name is followed by `:` (colon) and **the name/value pairs are separated by `,` (comma)**.

So there need to be a `,` between the `"cmd": ...` and the `"selector": ...` part.