# Set SublimeText for Python3...what does this command do?

Tags: python-3.x

I saw a lot of posts on the Internet give instructions for set Sublime text running Python, but nobody says what this command does and how it is composed.

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you talking about using the editor to run builds/scripts for you?

Comment: Exactly, run scripts directly in the Sublime editor

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/23730866/6529424

Comment: oh, sorry man...i didn't see it

Comment: @eagle33322 in that post nobody says something about the syntax used. Could you explaiin me that?